# Twitter login with React TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, twitter-oauth

I am running the React project on localhost:3000. I am trying to login with Twitter using React.

```
URL:  http://localhost:3000/login/

<TwitterLogin
    loginUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter"
    onFailure={this.onFailed}
    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
    requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter/reverse"
/>
```

When I clicked the Twitter login icon. I keep getting the error "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

And for the console, I am getting the following error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am also confused about what should I put for the Website URL and the Callback URL for the twitter developer settings. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What service runs on localhost:4000 (?)

Comment: I don't know I just followed this tutorial and it did not work for me. https://medium.com/@robince885/how-to-do-twitter-authentication-with-react-and-restful-api-e525f30c62bb

Answer (score -1):

[Refere their doc](https://github.com/GenFirst/react-twitter-auth#readme)

```
<TwitterLogin
    //localhost:4000 endpoint should be your api running url
    loginUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter"
    onFailure={this.onFailed}
    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
    //your api endpoint
    requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter/reverse"
/>
```

Comment: same error for me too but this doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

```
<TwitterLogin
    loginUrl="http://<API-endpoint>/api/v1/auth/twitter"
    onFailure={this.onFailed}
    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
    //your api endpoint
    requestTokenUrl="http://<API-endpoint>/api/v1/auth/twitter/reverse"
/>
```

Do not use localhost since you can get cors errors. See documentation for cors.

Comment: Hello, I changed it and I am getting a different error " SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Comment: can you create a sandbox

Answer (score -1):

Try another package [`react-twitter-login`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-login)

This Implementation not used any backend and created for simple OAuth with Twitter:

```
import React from "react";
import TwitterLogin from "react-twitter-login";

export default props => {
  const authHandler = (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
  };

  return (
    <TwitterLogin
      authCallback={authHandler}
      consumerKey={CONSUMER_KEY}
      consumerSecret={CONSUMER_SECRET}
      callbackUrl={CALLBACK_URL}
    />
  );
};
```